# Error when passing array pointer into a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I'm working on this project practicing my object oriented programming but having an issue when trying to call my `display()` function at the end of main.cpp. I created a Rectangle object named `rectangles` which is an array using pointers.

Basically what I am trying to do is pass my `rectangles` array into the `display()` function so I can print from there but I am getting the errors:

- Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: `void display(Rectangle *)` `void display(Rectangle * *)` '
- no matching function for call to 'display'

I've been trying to fix this for a few hours now and cant seem to get it working. Apologize if this is a simple mistake but I would love some input on how to get it working.

"main.cpp"

```
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>
#include <ctime> //for the time function
#include <cstdlib> //for rand and srand

using namespace std;

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 21, //size of the array
          MIN_VALUE = 1, //min value for random numbers
          MAX_VALUE = 7; //max value for random numbers

void display(Rectangle*); //prototype for display function

int main() {

    unique_ptr<Rectangle> rectangles(new Rectangle[ARRAY_SIZE]);

    double rectWidth;   // local variable for width
    double rectLength;  // local variable for length

    //for random numbers:
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);

    //inputs random numbers into rectWidth and rectLength
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i ++)
    {
        rectWidth = (rand() % (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE + 1)) + MIN_VALUE; //sets random number to Width
        rectLength = (rand() % (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE + 1)) + MIN_VALUE; //sets random number to Length

        rectangles->setWidth(rectWidth); //inputs Width to the setWidth function
        rectangles->setLength(rectLength); //inputs Length to the setLengh function
    }

    display(rectangles);

    return 0;
}
```

rectangle.cpp

```
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

Rectangle::Rectangle(double w, double len)   //constructor
{
    width = 0.0;
    length = 0.0;
}

Rectangle::~Rectangle()    //destructor
{

}

//******************************************************************
// setWidth assigns a value to the width member.
//**********************************************************************
void Rectangle::setWidth(double w)
{
    width = w;
}

//*********************************************************************
// setLength assigns a value to the length member.
//*********************************************************************
void Rectangle::setLength(double len)
{
    length = len;
}

//********************************************************************
// getWidth returns the value in the width member.
//********************************************************************
double Rectangle::getWidth() const
{
    return width;
}

//***********************************************************************
// getLength returns the value in the length member.
//***********************************************************************
double Rectangle::getLength() const
{
    return length;
}

//********************************************************************
//display will print out a report of the rectangles lable, hight, and width
//********************************************************************
void display(Rectangle* r[])
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 21;
    Rectangle *rectangles[ARRAY_SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << "Square\n\n";
        cout << "================\n\n";
        cout << "Label  Width   Hight\n";
        cout <<"R" << setfill('0') << setw(4) << i+ 1 << "  ";
        cout << rectangles[i]->getWidth() << "  ";
        cout << rectangles[i]->getLength() <<endl;

        delete rectangles[i]; //to delete the pointer
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered A) using a `std::vector` rather than a old-school array (or, if you really insist, a `std::array`)? B) using range-for loops? C) using the ctor initialization lists rather than the ctor body? D) reading a book on modern C++?

Comment: You should create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The error itself is pretty straightforward. You cannot pass `unique_ptr<Rectangle>` to function that requires `Rectangle*`.

Answer (score 4):

You have

```
void display(Rectangle*); //prototype for display function
```

and implement that as

```
void display(Rectangle* r[])
```

but you call it using this variable

```
unique_ptr<Rectangle> rectangles(new Rectangle[ARRAY_SIZE]);
```

Obviously that doesn't match either the declaration or the definition of the function.

The compiler believes that you have two different functions, one taking a pointer and one taking <strike>a pointer to an array</strike> an array of pointers. Neither matches the smart pointer.

Comment: My question is what steps do I need to take in order to fix this?

Comment: @Bryceqp As suggested by **Jesper Juhl** in the comments above, using a `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the display function parameter  as pointer, but while defining it, you are passing pointer array.